# How to Implement Asynchronous Queue to run Method in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous

First off, some basic information about my project: I have a website built with Symfony 3. For some tasks I'm thinking about implementing to run asynchronous PHP methods. Some events use a lot of time but their results need not be immediately evident.

For instance: in method `newOrder` I have function addUserLTV who do few steps. The customer does not have to wait for all the steps to complete, only to get immediately the confirmation after the basic operation - 'newOrder' will add `addUserLTV` to queue and show immediately confirmation (finished run). 
The queue tasks will be run when the server have time to do it.

```
public function addUserLTV( $userID, $addLTV )
{ //same code
}
```

How to do it? It is possible in symphony 3?

Comment: Pick the most suitable bundle from https://packagist.org/search/?q=queue-bundle and ask if you have any particular **coding** problems

Comment: What is the best in your opinion?

Comment: It is not a matter of opinion. You need to consider which queue manager you are going to use, and try one of the bundles that supports queue protocol of your choice. Please do some research. The question is too broad.

Comment: Also, if you haven't decided yet which queue manager will you use, [this bundle](https://github.com/bernardphp/BernardBundle) will be helpful. That's bundle for Bernard queue abstraction, so you can use it with a lot of different queues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is something you can easily do with [enqueue bundle](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev). Just a few words on why should you choose it:

- It supports [a lot of transports](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/tree/master/docs/transport) from the simplest one (filesystem) to enterprise ones (RabbitMQ or Amazon SQS).
- It comes with a very powerful [bundle](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/bundle/quick_tour.md).
- It has a top level abstraction which could be used with the greatest of ease.
- There are a lot more which might come in handy.

Regarding your question. Here's how you can do this with the enqueue bundle. Follow [setup instructions from the doc](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/bundle/quick_tour.md#install).

Now the `addUserLTV` method will look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Acme;

use Enqueue\Client\ProducerInterface;

class AddUserLTVService
{
    /**
     * @var ProducerInterface
     */
    private $producer;

    /**
     * @param ProducerInterface $producer
     */
    public function __construct(ProducerInterface $producer)
    {
        $this->producer = $producer;
    }

    public function addUserLTV( $userID, $addLTV )
    {
        $this->producer->sendCommand('add_user_ltv', [
            'userId' => $userID, 
            'ltv' => $addLTV]
        );
    }
}
```

It sends the message to a message queue using the client (top level abstraction I've mentioned before). The service has to be registered to the Symfony container:

```
services:
    Acme\AddUserLTVService: 
        arguments: ['@enqueue.producer']
```

Now let look at the consumption side. You need a command processor that do the job:

```
<?php
namespace Acme;

use Enqueue\Client\CommandSubscriberInterface;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrContext;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrMessage;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrProcessor;
use Enqueue\Util\JSON;

class AddUserTVAProcessor implements PsrProcessor, CommandSubscriberInterface
{
    public function process(PsrMessage $message, PsrContext $context)
    {
        $data = JSON::decode($message->getBody());

        $userID = $data['userID'];
        $addLTV = $data['ltv'];

        // do job

        return self::ACK;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedCommand()
    {
        return 'add_user_ltv';
    }
}
```

Register it as a service with a `enqueue.client.processor` tag:

```
services:
    Acme\AddUserTVAProcessor: 
        tags:
            - {name: 'enqueue.client.processor'}
```

That's it for coding. Run the consume command and you are done:

```
./bin/console enqueue:consume --setup-broker -vvv
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I do all this things ... but my job in process method not do :(

Comment: I just ran into a few issues, try to set up a command. I noticed 2 important things: `getSubscribedCommand` should return some lowercase name, and for some reason it tends to "stick" in cache. Unfortunately, if no matching Processor is found, the message is dropped silently, so that's hard to debug. Clear cache every time you modify it, and don't hesitate to add some `dump()` in `ContainerAwareProcessorRegistry` to ease debugging.